# unable to upload artifact to jfrog

Tags: gitlab-ci, put, jfrog-cli

I am trying to upload a ogg file to jfrog but I am getting the below error, would you mind helping me with what is wrong? I am running below code in my gitlab-ci file.

```
++ curl -sSf -H 'X-JFrog-Art-Api: <API_KEY>' -X PUT -T dist/myfile.egg 'https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/dev/apps/myapp/myfile.egg;released=true;build.number=0.1'
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400 
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

The pattern for Upload a file to Artifactory with properties (metadata):

```
$ curl -sSf -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:<API_KEY>" \
       -X PUT \
       -T file.zip \
       'http(s)://<ARTIFACTORY_URL>/<REPO>/<PATH>/file.zip;released=true;build.number=1.0'
```

if I change my code as below it is working but it won't create a folder and put myfile.egg inside it.

```
 ++ curl -sSf -H 'X-JFrog-Art-Api: <API_KEY>' -X PUT -T dist/myfile.egg 'https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/dev/apps/myapp;released=true;build.number=0.1'
```

** additional try:
I tried below code and I am getting another error:

```
curl -H 'X-JFrog-Art-Api: <API_KEY>' -XPUT  'https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/dev/apps/myapp/myfile.egg' -T dist/myfile.egg

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   120    0   120    0     0    882      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   882
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 400,
    "message" : "Parent apps/myapp must be a folder"
  } ]
}Job succeeded
```

Comment: The last error ("Parent apps/myapp must be a folder") implies that the 2nd call that worked created a file named "apps/myapp", so now you can't treat it as a folder in your target upload path. Try to delete it and then try again your first call which looks fine, this time don't hide the error (i.e. without the -sSf) so you can see the cause. I suspect the first 400 you reported was already after several failed attempts that left a dirty repository.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove my file and upload the artifact by using below command and it worked.

```
curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: <API_KEY>" -XDELETE "https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/dev/apps/myapp/myfile.egg"

curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: <API_KEY>" -XPUT "https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/dev/apps/myapp/myfile.egg" -T "dist/test.zip"
```